# Why Winmerge 2.16.10.0 is using arrow keys as if the Alt key is pressed?

Tags: winmerge

I'm used to using the shortcuts Alt+DownArrow and Alt+UpArrow to navigate the differences.
Now pressing just the arrow keys causes Winmerge jump to the next difference!

Also, same behavior with Alt+LeftArrow and just LeftArrow.

So, dows anyone know what is happening ?

Are there any configurations somewhere for the shortcut keys ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have entered menu mode *File > Merge Mode*, where the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
is not required for moving between differences.

You may toggle this mode by hitting the <kbd>F9</kbd> key,
or by clicking on the File menu entry.

(Note: The addition of this mode to WinMerge was by my suggestion.)

[image]

Comment: thanks, that was it :)

now that we're talking merge, do you have a link that explains how to resolve conflicts with Winmerge (and TortoiseSVN) ? I tried but couldn't understand how it works

Comment: Sorry, I don't know TortoiseSVN.

Comment: It should be noted that the Merge Mode is persistent between program restarts because it is saved as option "Settings/MergingMode" in WinMerge.txt configuration file.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut (F9) seems not configurable to me.